# Identical Twitter Bootstrap file rendering differently on separate servers in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, webserver

Came across an interesting problem that's really stumped me when attempting to implement the Twitter Bootstrap framework today. The issue I was initially attempting to solve was the appearance of horizontal scrollbars in Chrome when I resized the browser close to the breakpoints in the responsive template.

To troubleshoot this, I decided to copy the starter template verbatim, which was displaying correctly for me on the Twitter Bootstrap site. For extra consistency, I altered the relative paths of the included Bootstrap resources to point directly at the same files hosted on Github.

Mind-bogglingly, the problem still occurred even using the exact same code. You can view a working example of the [broken version here](http://close.cx/starter.html). Just resize the window horizontally in the latest version of Chrome and you'll notice scrollbars will appear on the bottom when the width nears a breakpoint. On a hunch, I copied the same file over to a different server and...[it works](http://dev.iamspencerbrooks.com/starter.html)?!

I honestly don't have a clue what could be causing HTML/CSS/JS to be behaving differently in the same browser across two different servers. The closest I could find were discussions from developers transferring files from local to remote environments and/or using IE. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: for what it's worth, the broken version isn't broken for me in a freshly updated chrome on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Working fine for me on chrome check screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/vDJQf.png

Comment: For those wondering, it was zoom after all (and I feel rather dumb, but I'm not really surprised it was something so obvious!). I think what probably happened is I attempted to zoom in Photoshop while still having Chrome targeted, and since the zoom shortcuts are the same I unknowingly zoomed in on Chrome. The part that made it especially confusing was Chrome applied the zoom to only the specific tab that was having problems, while all other new tabs defaulted to the correct zoom level which threw me off the scent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing Chrome was zoomed in.